# Apply a list of functions to matrix and return a matrix as a result in R

Tags: r, matrix, functional-programming

I have a matrix of *n* columns and *m* rows and a list of *f* functions. Each function takes one row of the matrix and returns a single value, *p*.

What is the best way to generate a *f* columns by *m* rows matrix?

At present I am doing this:

```
# create a random 5x5 matrix
m <- matrix(rexp(25, rate=.1), ncol=5)

# example functions, in reality more complex but with the same signature
fs <- list(function(xs) { return(mean(xs)) }, function(xs) { return(min(xs)) } )

# create a function which takes a function and applies it to each row of m
g <- function(f) { return(apply(m, 1, f)) }

# use lapply to make a call for each function in fs
# use do.call and cbind to reshape the output from a list of lists to a matrix
do.call("cbind", lapply(fs, g))
```

Clarification edit: the above code does work, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant approach.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A matrix with the same number of rows as m, and the same number of columns as the length of fs, where each cell is the result for the function f on the row of m.

Comment: Please, use `set.seed(1234)` (or any other number) before create your random matrix to reproduce the same result as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've adapted @patL's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037037/2665011) to take a list of functions:

```
# create a random 5x5 matrix
m <- matrix(rexp(25, rate=.1), ncol=5)

# example functions, in reality more complex but with the same signature
fs <- list(function(xs) { return(mean(xs)) }, function(xs) { return(min(xs)) } )

# create a function which takes a function and applies it to each row of m
g <- function(f) { return(apply(m, 1, f)) }

# use sapply to make a call for each function in fs
# use cbind to reshape the output from a list of lists to a matrix
cbind(sapply(fs, g))
```

I am using this to score an ensemble of models, for example:

```
# models is a list of trained models and m is a matrix of input data
g <- function(model) { return(predict(model, m)) }
# produce a matrix of model scores
cbind(sapply(models, g))
```

Answer (score 4):

With `base` R you can do it in one line:

```
cbind(apply(m, 1, mean), apply(m, 1, min))

#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 13.287748 5.2172657
#[2,]  5.855862 1.8346868
#[3,]  8.077236 0.4162899
#[4,] 10.422803 1.5899831
#[5,] 10.283001 2.0444687
```

this is faster than the `do.call` approach:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  do.call("cbind", lapply(fs, g)),
  cbind(apply(m, 1, mean), apply(m, 1, min))
)
```

which yelds:

```
#Unit: microseconds
#                                       expr    min     lq     mean
#            do.call("cbind", lapply(fs, g)) 66.077 67.210 88.75483
# cbind(apply(m, 1, mean), apply(m, 1, min)) 57.771 58.903 67.70094
# median     uq     max neval
# 67.965 71.741 851.446   100
# 59.658 60.036 125.735   100
```

Comment: Your solution is good and nearly answered the question, however you don't use the list of functions fs so I can't accept it. I need the code to be flexible and take a list of operators, not write a new apply for each function.

Answer (score 0):

With data:

```
set.seed(11235813)

m <- matrix(rexp(25, rate=.1), ncol=5)

fs <- c("mean", "median", "sd", "max", "min", "sum")
```

You can do:

```
sapply(fs, mapply, split(m, row(m)), USE.NAMES = T)
```

Which returns:

```
          mean   median        sd      max       min      sum
[1,]  9.299471 3.531394 10.436391 26.37984 1.7293010 46.49735
[2,]  8.583419 2.904223 11.714482 28.75344 0.7925614 42.91709
[3,]  6.292835 4.578894  6.058633 16.92280 1.8387221 31.46418
[4,] 10.699276 5.688477 15.161685 36.91369 0.1049507 53.49638
[5,]  9.767307 2.748114 10.767438 24.66143 1.5677153 48.83653
```

Note:

It is the *slowest* one, comparing to both approaches proposed above.

Comment: That does work, but as you say it's pretty slow and that isn't great.